# onActivityResult does not display marker in google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the onMapClick on my map,  with that the users take a photo at that point and then return that image as a thumbnail back to that point the user has tapped.  The problem though is if I specify a position the OnMapClick and onActivityResult works.  example:

```
private LatLng point = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);
```

But if I use the point in 'onMapClick (LatLng point)'  and then add that to this:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, **LatLng point**) {
```

and then use that in my onActivityResult marker:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
 .position(point)
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
 .fromBitmap(bitmap));
 googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

then everything still works, but the image isn't displayed on the map at that point tapped.  Plus there is nothing in the logs saying anything.  So I am really confused!

here is my Camera intent and onActivityResult:

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

           root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
           + "/Your_Folder";
           imageFolderPath = root + "/saved_images";
           File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
           imagesFolder.mkdirs();
          imageName = "test.png";
          File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);

          fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

          takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                  TAKE_PICTURE);

      }

      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, LatLng point) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              Bitmap bitmap = null;
                  try {
                      GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                      bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(point)
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                  googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


          }
          }
      public void showFullImage(View view) {
            String path = (String) view.getTag();

            if (path != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

    }
```

Sorry if the code looks messy, but have been working on this problem for the last 4 days and have been adding, deleting code as I go along,  will tidy up when I get this working :-)

**EDIT**

I think what is happening is that when you point on the map in the `OnMapClickListener`  the `OnActivityResult` "forgets (if you will)" where to place the image.  Thus not giving any error messages and discards the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple program to display marker in a specific location....I dont know whether its useful to you...
Here is the code

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         

    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(13.0839, 80.2700);         

    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                                   

    .position(CIU).title("My Office")); 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code, but the problem is that this puts the marker at that specific location and not on the selected point on the map.

Comment: try this code..i'm not sure whether the code wil work r not   GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                   (int) event.getX(),
                   (int) event.getY());
               // latitude
               double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
               // longitude
               double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
               Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Nope, still no luck.  I might be wrong, but i think when you click on the map and take the photo and then return from `onActivityReturn`, i think then the app "forgot" on which point the users has clicked.  Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

the issue might be, that you'd have to check `if(savedInstancestate == null)` within `onCreate()` and only create the view when it is `null`; in order *not* to create a new `MapFragment`... while I can only assume, since the relevant parts are absent in the code provided (but it still seems likely).